# Gstreamer SDK for iOS - library binaries are missing

Tags: ios, sdk, gstreamer

1. I had downloaded the gstreamer 1.2.4 package for iOS from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/
2. I get linking errors when I compile iOS gstreamer tutorials.
3. When I checked for Libraries folder in  ~/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/ ,
   I see Libraries link to -> lib;
   But Versions/1.0/lib is missing in my installation.
4. I extracted the bom payload from the gstreamer-1.0-devel-1.2.4-ios-universal.pkg and it does not have  Version/1.0/lib and binaries.

I would like to know if anyone have come across this problem before and please let me know what I could be missing here. I could not find similar issues elsewhere in the web.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Went old school trying to understand why Versions/1.0/lib is missing.
Now I see this Versions/1.0/Gstreamer 200M binary which is a big FAT archive of armv7 (for devices) and x86(for emulator) binaries in a bundle.

I was new to Xcode, MAC environment as well.
Now I added GStreamer.framework into Build Phases' Library list and everything works well.